# DropDownList Generic with ViewComponent in .net core 2

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'd like to develop a ViewComponent with a dropdownlist that accepts a list of data passed from the outside.

This list could be a user list, a list of numbers, ...

This is my ViewComponent - Code.cs

```
 [ViewComponent(Name = "ddlNew")]
public class ddlNewViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public ddlNewViewComponent()
    {
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string labelText, string nameDDL, string fieldKeyName, string fieldDescName )
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>() {
             new SelectListItem {Text = "Text1", Value = "1" },
             new SelectListItem {Text = "Text2", Value = "2" },
        };

        ViewBag.LabelText = labelText;
        ViewBag.NameDDL = nameDDL;

        ViewData[nameDDL] = list;
        return View("Default");

    }
}
```

Code .cshtml

```
@{
    string nameDDL = ViewBag.NameDDL;
}

<div>
    @if ((ViewBag.LabelText != null) || (ViewBag.LabelText != ""))
    {
        <h4>@ViewBag.LabelText</h4>
    }
    @Html.CheckBox("Testo CheckBox", true)
    @Html.DropDownList(nameDDL, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData[nameDDL], "--Scegli--")
</div>
```

Call in page

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("ddlNew", new { labelText = "Hello", nameDDL = "pippoDDL", fieldKeyName = "idPippo", fieldDescName = "descName" })
```

How to pass all types of data? I did not understand how to create a generic list that is good for the dropdownlist

Comment: Why are you doing this? Use the built-in `SelectTagHelper`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1#the-select-tag-helper

Comment: thanks, I rate it as an alternative!